# Jquery Data table Fixed Header Not aligned

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've noticed that a lot of the issues on jquery data tables have to do with horizontal scrolling and misalignment of headers. My issue is different. I do not have horizontal scrolling, but my header doesn't align on page load. See image below.

[image]

It looks like each header varies based off of the length of text in the box. Before adding the fixed header, everything was aligned. Im wondering if anyone hasd experienced this and if so, how did you work around it?

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery DataTables version?

Answer (score 1):

See if calling [`fixedHeader.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedHeader.adjust()) will solve it. For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   'drawCallback': function( settings ) {
      var api = this.api();
      api.fixedHeader.adjust();
   }
});
```

It looks like you're displaying custom controls in the table and they may be initialized after jQuery DataTables calculates width of headings.

Comment: cannot ready property adjust of undefined, i dont think that function is in my js

Comment: @Monzingo, FixedHeader extension 3.0 is required, make sure you the [latest](https://datatables.net/download/index) files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by downloading the package through NPM and then applying the fixedHeader attribute to true on tale initialization

Answer (score 0):

Write,

```
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").width($(".dataTables_scrollHead").width());
```

Note:- I hope you have written `"scrollX": true`  If not then please write this line. It will enable horizontal scrollbar.